# If first 10 characters in a text file match - write to new file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been trying to create python script that splits a log file based on date but I'm in need of some advice as my experience is limited and I haven't found any article that could help me.

This is an example of my log file:

```
2020-01-27 23:01:12: RANDOMTEXT
2020-01-27 23:02:12: RANDOMTEXT
2020-01-27 23:03:12: RANDOMTEXT
2020-01-27 23:04:12: RANDOMTEXT
2020-01-27 23:05:12: RANDOMTEXT
2020-01-28 05:06:01: RANDOMTEXT
2020-01-28 05:07:01: RANDOMTEXT 
2020-01-28 05:08:01: RANDOMTEXT 
2020-01-28 05:09:01: RANDOMTEXT
2020-01-28 05:10:01: RANDOMTEXT
2020-01-30 05:11:01: RANDOMTEXT
2020-01-31 23:12:12: RANDOMTEXT
2020-01-31 23:13:12: RANDOMTEXT
2020-01-31 23:14:12: RANDOMTEXT
2020-01-32 05:15:01: RANDOMTEXT
2020-01-33 23:16:12: RANDOMTEXT
2020-01-33 23:00:12: RANDOMTEXT
2020-01-33 23:00:12: RANDOMTEXT
2020-01-33 23:00:12: RANDOMTEXT
2020-01-34 05:00:01: RANDOMTEXT
2020-01-34 05:00:01: RANDOMTEXT
```

My idea was to create a while loop and a for loop, to loop through each line in the text file and check if the previous line had the same first 10 characters. If dates match the text line should be written to a a text file. Once the dates doesn't match it should create a new file with the name of the dates it adds to the file.

This is what I have so far:

```
f = open("textfile.txt")
lines = f.readlines()
linesingle = f.readline()
for line in lines:
    print (line)

    if "2020-01-28 " in line:
        print("EXISTS")
```

**EDIT**

Mattia Peracchi's answer gave me the simple solution I needed with some last code added. Simply takes the first 10 characters and puts those lines into a text file for itself generated with the same 10 first characters.

I just enter the date of the first line of code manually. I can easily add a variable but this works fine for what I need.

All the code in the end:

```
f = open("tekstfile.log", "r",encoding="utf8")
global prev_line
prev_line = '2020-01-27' #at least 10 char to avoid IndexError
for line in f.readlines():
    if line[:10] == prev_line[:10]:
        f2 = open(prev_line[:10], "a", encoding="utf8")
        f2.write(line)
        f2.close()
    prev_line = line

f.close()
```

Thank you for all your answers.

Comment: Can you show what would be the desired result in this example? As far as I can tell, none of the first 10 characters of any line match the previous line in the example, so it is not clear to me what your goal is.

Comment: I've updated the log file in the post. Here the first 10 characters match. For each new date between lines it should create file and add all lines with that date to a file.

Comment: What is the issue? Which part are you struggling with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel like I have made this unnecessarily complex but here goes:

```
log = open('log.txt','r+')
line = log.readline()
i = 0
first_ten = line[:10]
while line: #will stop once it has gone through all lines
    a = open(f'{first_ten}.txt','a+')
    while line[:10] == first_ten: #as long as lines with same first 10 characters are being read,
        a.write(line)
        line = log.readline()  #go to next line and write again if same first ten
    a.close()
    first_ten = line[:10]
```

Comment: Works way faster than the other result. Practically instantly splits the lines correctly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is a good job for the mighty [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby). It can be used to split sequences based on some property, in this case the first 10 characters.

If your log file is named `my_log_file.log` and you want to write to files named e.g. `2020-01-27.log` you can do

```
from itertools import groupby
with open("my_log_file.log") as f:
    for i, j in groupby(f, key=lambda x: x[:10]):
        # i is the name of the group e.g. "2020-01-27"        
        with open(f'{i}.log', 'w') as outf:
            for line in j:
                outf.write(line)
```

This will give you files such as

```
# 2020-01-27.log
2020-01-27 23:01:12: RANDOMTEXT
2020-01-27 23:02:12: RANDOMTEXT
2020-01-27 23:03:12: RANDOMTEXT
2020-01-27 23:04:12: RANDOMTEXT
2020-01-27 23:05:12: RANDOMTEXT
```

Comment: Thank you, I will save this as an alternative but I already got what I needed with a simpler answer and without importing a library.

Answer (score 0):

Using a for loop is a good idea, a while loop shouldn't be necessary:

```
with open("textfile.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

# initialise variables using data in the first line
current_date = lines[0][:10]
f = open(current_date + ".txt", 'a')
for line in lines:
    # check the date
    date = line[:10]
    # if it's the not same date as on the previous line,
    # close the file, open a new one, and overwrite the current_date variable
    if date != current_date:
        f.close()
        f = open(date + ".txt", 'a')
        current_date = date
    f.write(line + '\n')  # write with a new line character
f.close()
```

Note that `'a'` stands for append mode (adding a new line to the file each time, instead of overwriting the old data). So if you run it twice without clearing the files, you will duplicate the output.

Answer (score -1):

The `open` function with "a" (append only) access mode will create the file if it does not exist or open it if it exists, and then write the line after all existing lines. This puts all dates that match in the corresponding files.

```
f = open("textfile.txt")
lines = f.readlines()

for line in lines:
    print (line)
    f2 = open(line[:10] + ".txt", "a")
    f2.write(line)
    f2.close()
```